# JQuery ignore html created with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html table and it's content created with ajax
And I have a button which adds a row at the begining of the table
But JQuery don't know about the ajax content and adds row only after it

```
$("#add-row-first").on("click", addrowfirst);
function addrowfirst(){
    $("#table").prepend("<tr><td>1</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>");
}
```

ajax

```
function genTable(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "inc/gen-table.php",
        success: function(data){
            $("#table").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

html

```
<button id="add-row-first">create row</button>
<table id="table"></table>
```

**SOLUTION**
So the solution was very simple.
My ajax reqest return string `"<tr><td>some text</td></tr>"`.
So there is no `<tbody>` tag and the prepend insert code into tbody tag which not exsists.
And it automaticly creates it after ajax generated code. So your ajax should return `<tbody><tr><td>some text</td></td></tdbody>`

Comment: `$("#add-row-first").on("click", addrowfirst);`

Comment: Are you sure the ajax data is actually being added within the `<table>` tag? Could you post the code that adds the ajax content to the table?

Comment: it is very hard to tell you the solution without knowing what your ajax call is actually doing..

Comment: Your "solution" should not have been the problem as browsers normally compensate for a missing `tbody` element. What you should not have been doing is replacing the entire table `html`, but instead removing/appending rows.

Answer (score 0):

if element `#add-row-first` is created after the document is created you can't use it that way. You can use the `.on()` with another parameter so it will find the element like this instead

```
$("#table").on("click", "#add-row-first",addrowfirst);
```

If I am understanding your issue correctly, this should do it. The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is a little hard to digest, but basically, the first element `#table` needs to exist at the time of the document being loaded, and the element `#add-row-first` can be added to the DOM later, as long as it is a child of `#table` jQuery knows how to find it.

Comment: This was my first thought, but the question wording implies it actually adds the row, just not in the correct position. P.S. That thing you are trying to describe is a *delegated event handler* :)

Comment: I'm not sure, I think the entire `#table` element may be loaded after DOM creation. Also using that terminology doesn't make it easier to understand. Thanks for the correct technical name though. :)

Comment: So long as the button `add-row-first`exists then it should work. There is ore going one than they show :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure without more input from the OP.

Answer (score -2):

Simplest solution of this case could be

```
var data = "<tr><td>1</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td><td>cell</td></tr>";
$('#table').html( data + $('#table').html());
```

Comment: Did you try your suggestion? Assuming `#table` refers to a `table` tag then `.html()`  returns something like `<tbody>...</tbody>` concatenating it with `data` would result in `<tr>....</tr><tbody>...</tbody>` and this is invalid, and cause of that the `table` will become empty.